# Hide Resolved Stories in Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

How can I configure the Stories Backlog so that Resolved stories are not displayed (or are displayed in the bottom of the list) ?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the [July 1st](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-07-01-vso.aspx) update to VSO (TFS on-prem version [2013.3](http://www.visualstudio.com/news/release-archive-vso)) an option was added at the top of the backlog to Show/Hide in progress work items on the backlog.

If you are just after removing "Resolved" and not other active states - you can only do this in TFS on-prem:

Export the Process Config from your TFS:

```
witadmin exportprocessconfig /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DemoCollection /p:"TeamProjectName" /f:processconfig.xml
```

And have a look for a line similar to the following and relating to Requirements:

```
<State value="Resolved" type="InProgress" />
```

Change the value `type="InProgress"` to match another State (same as your Active State's type maybe).